# Is the normal product distribution sub-gaussian?

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics, probability-distributions

Consider the [normal product distribution](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NormalProductDistribution.html), which is the distribution of the product of two or more independent normal variables. Particulary, focus in the case where the multiplied normal variables are $\mathcal{N}(0, 1)$.

[image]

Considering the following definition of subgaussian tail (taken from [1]):

[image]

**Does the normal product distribution have subgaussian tail?**

I have been doing some numerical experiments which suggest an affirmative answer ($a=0.1$):

[image]

[1] Matoušek, J. (2008). On variants of the Johnson–Lindenstrauss lemma. Random Structures & Algorithms, 33(2), 142-156.

Comment: did you know it is a difference of iid chi-squared distributions with one dof? this makes me guess that it is not sub-gaussian, as the tail of one of them is shaped like $\exp(-x/2-\ln(x)/2)$ which is eventually greater than anything like $e^{-ax^2}, a>0$

Comment: if you're just interested in the johnson-lindenstrauss lemma you can find a different component distribution for your matrices where it still holds, and have subgaussian tails (for instance, i think rademacher rvs work)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If it were subgaussian then we would have $E[e^{\lambda X Y}] < \infty$ for all $\lambda$.  However, by conditioning and using independence we find
$$E[e^{\lambda X Y}] = E[E[e^{\lambda X Y} \mid X]] = E[e^{\lambda^2 X^2/2}]$$
which is easily seen to be infinite for all $\lambda \ge 1$.

Comment: I see, thank you for your answer. However, in my numerical simulations you can see that $P[x>\lambda] \le e^{-0.1\lambda^2}$ is true, except maybe for a very small amount at the end of the tail. Can this be interpreted as being "almost" subgaussian? In the sense that in practice such a small violation of the condition might not be problematic.

Comment: @DanielLópez: The "end of the tail" is the whole point in the definition of subgaussian.  If you choose a larger range for $\lambda$, things will look more dramatic.  I suggest a log scale.  I don't know what you mean by "not problematic"; I don't think you will be able to prove *any* of the usual helpful consequences of the subgaussian property if you assume $P(X > \lambda) \le e^{c \lambda^2}$ for *small* $\lambda$ only.